# Symbol explanation (vector, floor, times symbol)

Tags: vectors

I am not sure how to interpret the $\times$ symbol in the below usage:

$$2\lfloor e\times \rfloor$$ where $e = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$

Note that the $\times$ here, is not a variable of course, but a symbol.

(This is part of a bigger equation but I am omitting it now to simplify the question)

**Update 1**

After "staring" at the equation for some time, I realized that the authors are using the above representation, i.e. $\lfloor e\times \rfloor$ to symbolize a $3\times3$ **skew symmetric matrice**! That is $[e]_\times$.

Thanks!

Comment: You should post the whole equation. Maybe someone will recognize it. Then it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: As written, this is meaningless, in two respects: the cross product is missing an argument and you don't take the floor of a vector. There is no obvious way to fix, please provide more context.

Comment: After "staring" at the equation for some time, I realized that the authors are using the above representation, i.e. $\lfloor e\times \rfloor$ to symbolize a skew symmetric matrice! That is $[e]_\times$.